# Circled minus sign in Operator theory

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I found "circled minus" sign when I read one paper in Operator theory. What does that means? It was $H^{2}\ominus u H^{2}$. What does this mean and where can I find explanation for this?

Comment: Such questions are lacking context when posted like that. What was the subject of studies when you came across that ? What is $u$ ? What is $H$ ?

Comment: $H^{2}$  is a Hilbert space defined in the paper and u is some function. This is the first time I came across this and it was in Sarason paper on genralized interpolation in $H^\infty$

Comment: @Rebellos: the "subject of study", as mentioned in the question and the tag, is Operator Theory. In Operator Theory, things happen on Hilbert spaces.  For Hilbert spaces, the notation $H\ominus K$ is common.

Comment: @MartinArgerami By saying subject of study I reffered to something more specific. Also while I've been studying Functional Analysis and Operator Theory a lot, we have never used that notation despite using the definition of the set mentioned below.

Comment: @Rebellos: of the top of my head, the notation appears in Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", which is a canonical reference for "operator theory-oriented" functional analysis. I know I've seen it in many papers. All I can say is that it is very common.

Comment: Intuitively, it's a sort of inverse of the orthogonal direct sum $\oplus$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *orthogonal difference*. That is, for a subspace $K\subset H$, 
$$
H\ominus K=\{x\in H:\ x\perp K\}=K^\perp\cap H. 
$$
When $H$ is the biggest Hilbert space you have around, $H\ominus K$ is simply $K^\perp$; but often times, as in the example you mention, one is considering an inclusion of subspaces, and so the orthogonal difference is the "relative orthogonal complement".